# Create and use an Enum in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, enums

I'm currently developing a poker game for iOS in Objective-C, but I'm having issues with using [enums](/questions/tagged/enums). I would like to create an `enum` called "Suit" and use it in my Card class, since every card would have its deck and suit such as "Ace Spade".

Where do I define my `enum`?

```
typedef enum Suit {
    Diamond,
    Club,
    Heart,
    Spade
}
```

Also, what type of class should I define the Suit `enum` in (ex. `NSObject`, `UIView`, etc.)?
And, after I import `Suit.h` in `Card.h`, can I define it as property directly in `Card.h`?

I'm not very familiar with Objective-C, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to add a semicolon at the end?  And why are you defining it with typedef, while not adding an alias to the enum at the end?

Comment: And to address your problem, if the Card class is the only class that uses Suit, then you can just add Suit in your Card's header.  There's no strict rule to follow where you're suppose to put an enum, just put it where classes that requires it can easily access it.

Comment: "for the Suit header class, what class type should it be?(subclass of what, NSObject or..?" <- enums are not classes.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer as I said I don't know much about objective-c enum. Card is gonna be used for several times in several classes.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks for telling, Quuxplusone 's sample is much clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
typedef enum {
    Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades
} Suit;

typedef int Value;

struct Card {
    Suit suit;
    Value value;
};
```

or, if you really think `Card` needs to be a heavyweight class, then

```
@interface Card : NSObject
@property Suit suit;
@property Value value;
@end
```

Comment: You can also use the `NS_ENUM` macro to more cleanly type your enums. Look in the UIKit headers, e.g. `UIView.h` - they use it for all the UIView enums.